# FHIR Extension displays ?gen-e1? in IG

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have been playing around with FHIR for a few weeks and Extensions have been causing me some confusion. I have a resource derived from Basic that contains two extensions (one based off of ImagingStudy and the other off of Device). However, when I build the IG, I don't see the Referenced type properties available for inspection. Am I doing something incorrectly with my defintions?

[image: IG with extensions]

I have also read that when creating extensions, I need to publish them so that they can be referenced (maybe this is part of the original problem?). Is there a good reference or tutorial that describes the publishing process? I would like to push to my local system.

Any other resources that folks could recommend to a beginner would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: In terms of publishing them, you have a few choices - you can put them in a registry such as registry.fhir.org or simplifier.net, or you can host your own server that exposes them.

Answer (score 0):

oh that shouldn't happen. can you report a bug here https://github.com/HL7/fhir-ig-publisher/issues wihth a link to a github repo branch or a zip that reproduces it?